# How to set up my Gigabyte GT-E8000 TV card to work?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, multimedia, tv-tuner, remote-control

I have a Gigabyte GT-E8000 hybrid HD TV-tuner in my system. I wonder if I could make it work, tried several softwares, but no luck at all.

I usually watch analogue broadcast (through cable-TV) and digital DVB-T as well, so both would be nice to work, and the remote controller too (I have another remote controller, which designed to work with Windows Media Center).

The TV card has an NXP chipset (NXP SAA7160 Hybrid Capture Device), and connected to PCI-Ex1 interface.
If someone has any solutions or workaround to make it work, please share with me, and of course if there's a good software for watching TV, recording,  that would be nice too:)!

Comment: OP advises: "This question is not abandoned, i'm still waiting for the solution. There's no way to repost this question because the system warned me that this is a duplicated entry."

Comment: Have you checked if it will work with Mythbuntu? http://www.mythbuntu.org/ I know it's not exactly the solution you're looking for, but if the Live CD works we know that it *should* work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't checked yet with the Mythbuntu Live CD, but i'll giv it a try.

Comment: I've tried to install mythTV pacgages under Ubuntu 12.04, but under setup, the card wasn't shown up. By my knowledge the actual kernel includes some of the similar Philips/NXP drivers, but i don't know how to make it work with this card. I'm unfortunately just trying out new features of the new releases, and will be very happy if all the components of my setup will work without any problems. That's the goal to finally migrate from Win7 to Ubuntu or similar...